# Ionic/NodeJS/MEAN - Put clears object data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, mean-stack

I am currently working on a MEAN stack app using Node/Express and Ionic/Angular. I have a page where the user can edit/delete the content of a particular object. The delete function works, but when I click the edit and trigger the put/update function it clears the data except for the id number and "__v": 0 instead of updating the object.

I've checked the server side API with Postman and it can be updated with the body content type x-form-urlencoded. My hunch is getting the data correctly on the client side. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is my code for the Ionic/Angular Controller:

```
   .controller('UpdateCtrl', function($stateParams, $rootScope, $scope, HomeFac) {  
id = $stateParams.id;  

$scope.location = {}; 

HomeFac.getLocation(id).success(function(data) {  
     $scope.location = data; 
});


$scope.edit = function() {  

    meet = $scope.location;  
    location = angular.fromJson(meet);
    console.log(location); 

    HomeFac.updateLocation(id, location)
     .then(function(id, location) 
     { 
       console.log("good"); 
     });  
}; 

$scope.delete = function() { 
   HomeFac.deleteLocation(id);
}; 

});
```

Server Side:

```
exports.putLocation = function(req, res) {
 // Use the Beer model to find a specific beer
 Location.findById(req.params.location_id, function(err, location) {

// Update the existing location 
location.name = req.body.name; 
location.category = req.body.category;  
location.latitude = req.body.latitude; 
location.longitude = req.body.longitude; 
// Save the beer and check for errors
location.save(function(err, location) {
  if (err) { 
    res.send(err)
  };

  res.json(location);
 });
 });
};
```

HomeFac update function

```
 _LocationService.updateLocation = function(_id, location) { 
 return $http.put(urlBase + '/' + _id, location); 
};
```

Comment: Did you enable `bodyParser.json()` in your middleware stack?

Comment: @PrashanthChandra. Yes. On my server.js I have bodyParser.json() and added bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}).

Comment: Also, in `exports.putLocation` you're only reading `req.params`. If you PUT JSON to the server, `req.params` would be empty, the data would be in `req.body` instead. You have to account for that.

Comment: try `if (req.body) location = req.body; else {location.name = req.params.name...}`

Comment: When you send data with `x-form-urlencoded`, the data is in `req.params.<property of object>`, whereas with `application/json`, the data is in `req.body`

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose is returning a 'Mongoose Document' instead of a standard JSON object so if your properties that you are trying to update are not in your Schema they will not be added to the location document.

If all you are doing is updating a document you don't need to call findById first. You can do an Update query, so pass in an _id to find and then an update object. This will update the existing document

```
exports.putLocation = function(req, res) {

    var query = { _id: req.body.location_id };

    var update = {
        $set: {
            name: req.body.name,
            category: req.body.category,
            latitude: req.body.latitude,
            longitude: req.body.longitude
        }
    };

    Location.update(query, update, function (err, location) {

        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        } 

        res.json(location);
    });
};
```

Comment: Just tried this out. On Postman it works but with My Angular form it doesn't.

Comment: Could be Postman is doing a POST request and your form is a PUT request. I would play around with a POST or try change req.body to req.params and see what happens. Sorry, not too familiar with PUT

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the solution to it. I had to modify my controllers on the client side and the server side. On the server side, I am using findByIdAndUpdate for the action. For the benefit of those who may experience this problem, I've posted my code below.

Server side:

```
exports.putLocation = function(req, res) {
// Use the Location model to find a specific location
Location.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.location_id, req.body,     
  function(err, location) { 
    if (err) 
      res.send(err); 
     res.json({ data: location }); 

 }); 
};
```

Client Controller

```
 .controller('UpdateCtrl', function($state, $stateParams, $rootScope, $scope, HomeFac) {  

id = $stateParams.id;   

$scope.location = {};

HomeFac.getLocation(id).success(function(data) {  
   $scope.location = data;  
}); 

$scope.edit = function() { 

   name = $scope.location.name;
   cat = $scope.location.category;  
   lat = $scope.location.latitude; 
   long = $scope.location.longitude; 

   mark = { name: name, category: cat, latitude: lat, longitude: long }; 

   setmark = angular.toJson(mark);  

   HomeFac.updateLocation(id, setmark); 

   }


   $scope.delete = function() { 
     HomeFac.deleteLocation(id); 

      $state.go('home'); 
   }

});
```